# AWS - Face comparison command line mistake

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am new to 'AWS'.. I trying to compare two faces using command line.. I use this code for face comparison

```
aws rekognition compare-faces \
--source-image '{"S3Object":{"Bucket":"trailface","Name":"image4.jpg"}}' \
--target-image '{"S3Object":{"Bucket":"trailface","Name":"image5.jpg"}}'
```

After running this code I got `Unknown options: \, \`

[image]

After I removed the \ I got another problem
[image]

Help me to solve this...

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean by compare? Do you want to check if faces in both files are similar or compare if these two images are equal? Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your reply@pb772 ..I want to check both faces are similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the result.. The correct code format is

```
aws rekognition compare-faces 
--source-image "S3Object{Bucket=trailface,Name=image1.jpg}" 
--target-image "S3Object={Bucket=trailface,Name=image9.jpg}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove  \, \  from you command as syntax for the command is as follows:

```
 compare-faces
 [--source-image <value>]
 [--target-image <value>]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Yash Bindlish.. I made the changes you said. After that I got another problem I posted it in above. can you pls clarify ...

Comment: did you put these brackets `[ ]`?